# Ressources not found | ANT Rename application package

Tags: android, ant, package, android-manifest, rename

After lots of digging i found the solution how i can rename my application package. It's working great.

There are two different ways. The one via arg params:

```
<!-- Replaces the target in tools\ant\build.xml -->
<target name="-package-resources" depends="-crunch">
            <!-- this exec replicates the output of the aapt task in build.xml
                 -package-resources with the addition of a rename-manifest-package option. -->
            <exec executable="${aapt}" failonerror="true">
                <arg value="package" />
                <arg value="-f" />
                <arg value="--auto-add-overlay" />
                <arg value="-M" />
                <arg path="${basedir}/AndroidManifest.xml" />
                <arg value="-S" />
                <arg path="${resource.absolute.dir}" />
                <arg value="-S" />
                <arg path="${basedir}/${android.library.reference.1}/${resource.dir}" />
                <arg value="-A" />
                <arg path="${asset.absolute.dir}" />
                <arg value="-I" />
                <arg path="${android.jar}" />
                <arg value="-F" />
                <arg path="${out.absolute.dir}/${resource.package.file.name}" />
                <arg value="--rename-manifest-package" />
                <arg value="${package.manifest.name}" />
            </exec>
</target>
```

or the direct one (like the original build.xml does):

```
<target name="-package-resources" depends="-crunch">
        <!-- only package resources if *not* a library project -->
        <do-only-if-not-library elseText="Library project: do not package resources..." >
            <aapt executable="${aapt}"
                    command="package"
                    versioncode="${package.manifest.version.code}"
                    versionname="${package.manifest.version.name}"
                    debug="${build.is.packaging.debug}"
                    manifest="${out.manifest.abs.file}"
                    assets="${asset.absolute.dir}"
                    androidjar="${project.target.android.jar}"
                    apkfolder="${out.absolute.dir}"
                    nocrunch="${build.packaging.nocrunch}"
                    resourcefilename="${resource.package.file.name}"
                    resourcefilter="${aapt.resource.filter}"
                    libraryResFolderPathRefid="project.library.res.folder.path"
                    libraryPackagesRefid="project.library.packages"
                    previousBuildType="${build.last.target}"
                    buildType="${build.target}"
                    ignoreAssets="${aapt.ignore.assets}"
                    manifestpackage="${package.manifest.name}">
                <res path="${out.res.absolute.dir}" />
                <res path="${resource.absolute.dir}" />
                <!-- <nocompress /> forces no compression on any files in assets or res/raw -->
                <!-- <nocompress extension="xml" /> forces no compression on specific file extensions in assets and res/raw -->
            </aapt>
        </do-only-if-not-library>
    </target>
```

The problem now is that a library i use can't find it's ressources (it's a lib, and i had to include the graphics in my app). So the ressources are in my apps res dir.

The same thing also happens if i try to load a specific ressources (dynamically) from my package. I used ctx.getApplicationPackage() to get the packagename. As long as i use this method it was not working for the renamed version, but as soon as i tried it hardcoded with the package name of the main app it works.

So i assume the references don't updated. Let's say i have app 1 with package com.package.appfinal and app 2 with com.package.apptest. The ressources are still found in com.package.appfinal.

I hope someone has an idea how i can extend the rename process so the ressources are also updated? (or their references)

Thanks in advance.

Cheers,
-- Mike

Comment: Did you find a way to do this?