# android 9 patch image do not stretch in release mode

Tags: android, release, nine-patch, build.xml

I am using some 9-patch images for buttons in my app.

When I launch from eclipse, all is fine, but when I build in release mode (ant/proguard obfuscation, ...) and install the apk, the 9-patch images do not stretch correctly in the application (stretch like normal png, showing the black borders ...).

I looked into the apk and the *9.png files seem normal. All other images are displayed correctly. I tryed to disable the -crunch target, and also added the nocompress option in the packaging target but no luck.

Any clue on what this could come from ? (I assume it is related to the ant build - I am using adt tools v20).

Thanks in advance

pierre-g

Comment: Also, yes, I did a full clean, eclipse stop/start and full rebuild, clean install, ..... and tested on rooted/non rooted devices (2.3.3 and 3.1).

Comment: Hi,

finally found the solution. 

The nine-patch images were in a library project (I split the project recently). To be sure, I first did copy the nine-patch images in the app project res folder and they displayed correctly (when building the release apk). 

So the issue was in the build.xml package-resources target. The reference to the library was not there (so the crunch was only on the project res folder).

Updated the target with the proper arg like in [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12300521/ressources-not-found-ant-rename-application-package)

All is fine now.